# Use thrust reduce_by_key on a struct

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm fairly new to CUDA and I'm trying to apply a `reduce_by_key` operation on a struct.

```cpp
struct index_and_loc {
  int index;
  int3 location;
}
```

What I would like to do is, I have a vector of `index_and_loc` where elements would have the same `index`

```cpp
thrust::host_vector<index_and_loc> my_vector;
my_vector= { {0, {0, 2, 5}},
             {0, {1, 3, 4}},
             {0, {0, 1, 3}},
             {1, {2, 1, 0}},
             {1, {2, 2, 2}}
           }
```

And I want to have two outputs, one would be the sum of all the elements that have the same index, and another vector that stores how many instances of each index. So my resulting outputs would be:

```cpp
// Sum all elements with index 0 and 1
sum_vector = {{0, {1, 6, 12}},
              {1, {4, 3, 2}}
             }

instances_vector = {3, // Number of elements with index = 0
                    2} // Number of elements with index = 1
```

Reading the methods in thrust documentation, I believe I should be using `reduce_by_key`. I can declare my `input1` be `my_vector` and `input2` be a vector of 1`s with the same length as `input1` and I can reduce using the index of my struct and use `thrust::plus<int>` as my BinaryFunction to the vector of 1`s. However this wouldn't be able to apply the sum of the `int3` elements in my input1 vector, as the BinaryFunction gets applied on `input2`.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Please let me know if my question isn't very clear.

EDIT:

I reworked the problem and brought it down to an easier approach. I have instead added an instance column to `my_vector` and set them to 1. Now, using talonmies answer, I can get the both answers I was looking for. Here's my code

```cpp
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

struct index_and_loc {
  int index;
  int3 location;
  int instance;

  index_and_loc() = default;

  __host__ __device__
  index_and_loc(int index_, int3 location_, int instance_) :
  index(index_), instance(instance_) {
    location.x = location_.x; 
    location.y = location_.y;
    location.z = location_.z;
  };

  __host__ __device__
  index_and_loc& operator=(const index_and_loc& y) {
    index = y.index;
    location.x = y.location.x;
    location.y = y.location.y;
    location.z = y.location.z;
    instance = y.instance;
    return *this;
  };

  __host__ __device__
  bool operator==(const index_and_loc& y) const {
    return index == y.index;
  };

  __host__ __device__
  index_and_loc operator+(const index_and_loc& y) const {
    return index_and_loc(index,
      make_int3(location.x + y.location.x, 
                location.y + y.location.y, 
                location.z + y.location.z),
      instance + y.instance);
  };

};

int main() {

  int num_points = 5;
  thrust::device_vector<index_and_loc> my_vector(num_points);
  my_vector.push_back(index_and_loc(0, {0, 2, 5}, 1));
  my_vector.push_back(index_and_loc(0, {1, 3, 4}, 1));
  my_vector.push_back(index_and_loc(0, {0, 1, 3}, 1));
  my_vector.push_back(index_and_loc(1, {2, 1, 0}, 1));
  my_vector.push_back(index_and_loc(1, {2, 2, 2}, 1));

  thrust::device_vector<index_and_loc> same_idx(num_points);
  thrust::device_vector<index_and_loc> sum_locs(num_points);

  thrust::equal_to<index_and_loc> pred;
  thrust::plus<index_and_loc> op;

  auto res = thrust::reduce_by_key(
    thrust::device,
    my_vector.begin(),
    my_vector.end(),
    my_vector.begin(),
    same_idx.begin(),
    sum_locs.begin(),
    pred,
    op);

  for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    index_and_loc y = same_idx[i];
    index_and_loc x = sum_locs[i];
    std::cout << y.index << " {" << x.location.x 
                         << " " << x.location.y 
                         << " " << x.location.z 
                         << "}, " << x.instance << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Running this will in fact give me

```sh
0 {1 6 12}, 3
1 {4 3 2}, 2
```

Comment: You could use a transform_iterator to create separate iterators for keys and values. Then use reduce by key with a custom reduction operation which performs element-wise addition of int3.

Comment: Alternatively, you would need to pass your structure as both data and key and then write custom functors for equality testing and the reduction operator so that the key comparison and the reduction work.. However, you won't get your instances_vector output from any form of reduce_by_key. That would require post hoc analysis of the output iterator

Comment: @talonmies I'm attempting your idea since I had thought the same at the beginning. However I'm encountering an error when calling reduce_by_key. I get
```bash
error: no instance of constructor "index_and_loc::index_and_loc" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (const thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<index_and_loc>>)
```
I'm guessing my struct needs a constructor with the iterator as argument and I'm not sure how to use this iterator in a constructor. I can post this as a new question if it's better

Comment: I can't tell you want mistakes you have made in code I can't see

Comment: @talonmies My apologies, I have edited my question, with a new approach following your suggestion and a working example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do in my example, but it doesn't look like what I had in mind (which is now in my answer below)

Comment: Your answer in fact was very helpful. I added my own approach and now I get both the answers I needed. I updated my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to potentially do what you want. I have no feeling for what will and will not be efficient, that is up to you to decide.

One approach is to define the necessary comparison and addition operators in your class and then use those wrapped in the pre-canned thrust binary functors for the required binary operator and predicate for the `reduce_by_key`call. For example:

```
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>

struct index_and_loc {
  int index;
  int3 location;

  index_and_loc() = default;

  __host__ __device__
  index_and_loc(int index_, int3 location_) {
      index = index_;
      location.x = location_.x;
      location.y = location_.y;
      location.z = location_.z;
  };

  __host__ __device__
  index_and_loc& operator=(const index_and_loc& y) {
      index = y.index;
      location.x = y.location.x;
      location.y = y.location.y;
      location.z = y.location.z;
      return *this;
  };

  __host__ __device__
  bool operator==(const index_and_loc& y) const {
      return index == y.index;
  };

  __host__ __device__
  index_and_loc operator+(const index_and_loc& y) const {
      return index_and_loc(index, make_int3(location.x + y.location.x, 
                                            location.y + y.location.y, 
                                            location.z + y.location.z));
  };
};

int main()
{
    thrust::host_vector<index_and_loc> my_vector(5); 
    my_vector[0] =  {0, {0, 2, 5}};
    my_vector[1] =  {0, {1, 3, 4}};
    my_vector[2] =  {0, {0, 1, 3}};
    my_vector[3] =  {1, {2, 1, 0}};
    my_vector[4] =  {1, {2, 2, 2}};

    thrust::device_vector<index_and_loc> d_vector = my_vector; 
    thrust::device_vector<index_and_loc> keys_out(5);
    thrust::device_vector<index_and_loc> data_out(5);

    thrust::equal_to<index_and_loc> pred;
    thrust::plus<index_and_loc> op;

    auto res = thrust::reduce_by_key(
            d_vector.begin(),
            d_vector.end(),
            d_vector.begin(),
            keys_out.begin(),
            data_out.begin(),
            pred,
            op);

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        index_and_loc y = keys_out[i];
        index_and_loc x = data_out[i];
        std::cout << y.index << " {" << x.location.x 
                             << " " << x.location.y 
                             << " " << x.location.z 
                             << "}" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

They key things is the correct definition of `operator==` for the predicate and `operator+` for the reduction. The rest is just required for copy assignment and construction.

This appears to do what you want:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -std=c++11 -o improbable improbable.cu
$ ./improbable 
0 {1 6 12}
1 {4 3 2}
```

Note that because thrust expects that key and data are separate iterators, you must have separate output iterators for the reduced keys and data. That means you effectively get two copies of the solution. Whether that is a big deal is for you to decide.

Comment: It is an awesome answer! Thank you!